# how to make python request.get wait a few seconds?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml, python-requests

I wanted to do get some experience with html crawling, so I wanted to see if I could grab some values of the following site: http://www.iex.nl/Aandeel-Koers/11890/Royal-Imtech/koers.aspx

This site shows the price of imtech shares. 
If you take a look at the site, you see there is 1 number shown in bold, this is the price of the share.

As you may have seen, this price changes, and that's okay. I only want the value at the time I run my script at this point in time.

but if you reload the page, you may notice how it first shows "laatste koers" and after a delay of 1 second it shows "realtime"

As you may have figured out by now, I'm interested in the "realtime" value.

Here is my question, how do I get this value, I've tried time.sleep(2) on different places. I've tried a timeout at the request. Both didn't work.

How can I fix this?

```
from lxml import html
import requests

pagina = 'http://www.iex.nl/Aandeel-Koers/11890/Royal-Imtech/koers.aspx'

page = requests.get(pagina)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

koers = tree.xpath('//span[@class="RealtimeLabel"]/text()')

prices = tree.xpath('//span[@id="ctl00_ctl00_Content_LeftContent_PriceDetails_lblLastPrice"]/text()')
print koers[0], pagina.split("/")[5], prices[0]
```

I get output like this

```
Laatste koers Royal-Imtech 0,093
```

While I want output like this

```
Realtime Royal-Imtech 0,093
```

Comment: I suspect that "Laatste koers" is being changed to "Realtime" by some javascript on the page, in which case there's no easy way to see what the page looks like after the script executes. I don't think `requests` executes user side scripts at all.

Comment: it is changed via javascript yes, but the "Laatste koers" Is also inserted via javascript

Comment: @zazga: `requests` and `lxml` are never going to execute the JS in the page; you'll have to reverse engineer that behaviour and do it yourself, *or* use something like Selenium to drive an actual browser that *does* execute JavaScript.

Comment: As such there is no point in putting in a delay here; that delay is caused by extra code (JavaScript code) being executed by the browser. That is not going to happen in your script.

Comment: Damn!! observed almost every request made, but couldnt find one that fetch that data (of course its js, but I guess there has to be a requests too) what I could say for now is that no matter how long you wait you will never find that element in the page source, since its not there in the response of the request even after the page completely loads. There has to be another call, just cant find it :-(

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest use a wait until the element changes.

Find the block of code below to help you.

```
def wait_while(condition, timeout, delta=1):
    """
    @condition: lambda function which checks if the text contains "REALTIME"
    @timeout: Max waiting time
    @delta: time after which another check has to be made
    """
    max_time = time.time() + timeout
    while max_time > time.time():
        if condition():
            return True
        time.sleep(delta)
    return False
```