# PYTHON : How to make my request.get() last for a few second?

Tags: python, request, sleep, tracker

To test my API, I need to send a request on my viewer url on which there is a tracking service that tell my API how many time I've spent on the page (classical).

I have this small function in my tests :

```
def does_it_track(response, **kwargs):
  # some unrelated actions
  r = requests.get('my_viewer_url')
```

This request works fine but it only last for less than a second and it doesn't allow me to test my statistic generator, neither the my tracker precision.

I've tried :

- This SO issue : [how to make python request.get wait a few seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280282/how-to-make-python-request-get-wait-a-few-seconds) it didn't help
- The sleep method (but I got `has no attribute 'sleep'`
- To repeat the request send, but it obviously create several stats and I only need a longer one

Does someone know about a "not-to-complicated-way" to make my request wait on my page ?

I'm python 2.7

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"how many time you've spent on the page" has nothing to do with the HTTP request/response cycle, but with your browser.

From the server's point of view, the server gets a request, returns a response and the job is over, period - and from the client's point of view once the server returned a response the HTTP transaction is over too. There's not even a notion of "page" here, only HTTP request and response.

Your "tracker" is (obviously) using javascript to send data from the browser itself (most likely by sending a request each X seconds indicating the page is still displayed in the browser). IOW, the only way to test this is to use a headless browser that will execute javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try VCR, it might help you to solve your issue.
Indeed you would be able to save your request and see what's happening.

[VCR](https://vcrpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Bruno is right, it can't solve my problem, anyway, VRC looks like a nice lib to use !